# How can I display a loading spinner while my Next image component loads when I had a previous image in place?

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to show a loading spinner (or really any HTML element for that matter) while my image is loading, the thing is I am using this ImageComponent to display an image in a random movie generator, I was able to get the spinner working just with the first image, but after that when I get a new movie the image of the previous movie stays until the new image is loaded.

Here's the code of the image component:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function ImageComponent(image: PrimaryImage) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  function onImageLoad() {
    setLoading(false)
    console.log("loaded")
  }

  return (
    <div className="relative h-full m-auto">
      <div style={{ display: loading ? "block" : "none" }}>
        Loading Spinner goes here
      </div>
      <Image className="object-contain"
        src={image.url}
        alt="Image"
        fill
        onLoad={onImageLoad}
        priority
        style={{ display: loading ? "none" : "block" }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

And here is the code of the full page:

```
"use client"
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { getMoviesRequest } from "./requests";
import MovieImageComponent from "./components/MovieImage";

export default function Page() {
  const moviesCache = useRef<Movie[]>([])
  const index = useRef(0)
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState<Movie>({
    titleText: { text: "" },
    primaryImage: { width: 0, height: 0, url: "/default_image.png" },
    releaseDate: { day: 0, month: 0, year: 0 }
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    refreshMoviesCache()
  }, [])

  function refreshMoviesCache() {
    // do some stuff to refresh the movies cache
  }
  function setNewMovie() {
    // do some stuff to set a new movie
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>
        Movie Generator
      </h3>
      {MovieImageComponent(movie.primaryImage)}
      <div className="text-center p-3">
        <h1>{movie.titleText.text}</h1>
        <h2>{movie.releaseDate.year}</h2>
        <button onClick={setNewMovie}>
          Otra Pelicula
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an if statement instead, like this:

```
<div className="relative h-full m-auto">
    {loading ?
       <div>
         Loading Spinner goes here
       </div>
     :
       <Image className="object-contain"
         src={image.url}
         alt="Image"
         fill
         onLoad={onImageLoad}
         priority
       />
    }
</div>
```

and you need to change the `loading` state every time that you send a request for new movie.

Comment: It didn't work for me if I use the if statement like you propose, but I did what you said about changing `loading`  state when seting a new movie and it worked, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure the Image component is exposed and not in the {isloading?  : <Image ...> } because It would never get started to be rendered. onLoad is a callback function that would be called after its image src is loaded.

```
 {!isLoaded && <Spinner />}
 <Image
  ...
  onLoad={() => onImageLoad()}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

you could have a state for default image

```
const [imageUrl,setImageUrl]=useState(yourDefaultImageUrl)
```

when image loads you have `onImageLoad`, and you set the final url here:

```
function onImageLoad() {
    setLoading(false)
    setImageUrl(image.url)
    console.log("loaded")
  }
```

as `src` use `imageUrl`

```
   <Image className="object-contain"
        src={imageUrl}
        alt="Image"
        fill
        onLoad={onImageLoad}
        priority
        style={{ display: loading ? "none" : "block" }}
      />
```

Comment: This didn't work for me but I guess it was because I still would need to reset `loading` to true when I set a new movie